# I want to calulate the range of an operator $S$ which maps $L^{2}$ into $H^{1}(\Omega)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

I have an equation $s(\lambda,\mu)=l(\mu)$, where s(.,.) is a symetric positive definite bilinear form in $L^{2}(\Omega)$,  and $l(.)$ is in $H^{1}(\Omega)$. I want to show that the range of the operator $S$ associated to $s(.,.)$ is $H^{1}(\Omega)$. Thank you

Comment: I don't get it. $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are in $L^2(\Omega)$ ? and you are considering the operator (for a fixed $\mu$) :  $\lambda \mapsto s(\lambda,\mu)$ ? what is in $H^1(\Omega)$ then ???

Comment: Do you want to solve $s(\lambda, \cdot) = l(\cdot)$ for $\lambda$ and show that $\lambda \in H^1(\Omega)$? This might depend on your precise $s$.

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. Please make your question more precise. How is the operator associated with $s$ defined? By $s(x,y) = \langle S(x),y \rangle$? And what do you mean by $\ell(\cdot) \in H^1$?

Comment: Thank you, this is my first time in math.stackexchange. I will try to be more precise. By Ritz representation s(λ,μ)=l(μ) can be rewritten as simplified equation: $S\lambda=l$, with $\lambda$ is in $L^{2}(\Omega)$, and $l\in H^{1}(\Omega)$. What i know is that the biliear form $s(.,.)$ is symmetric definite positive. And the question is that $Range(S)=H^{1}(\Omega)$?